# Find angles between list of sorted vertices using vertex.co.angle()

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, transforms

I am trying to use the technique described here [Python: Calculate angle between vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34926/python-calculate-angle-between-vertices) to determine the angles between a list of vertices that is sorted left to right on the x axis

```
        mylen2 = len(vertices)
    
        if(mylen2 > 1): 
            a1 = vertices[mylen2-1].co.angle(vertices[mylen2-2].co)
            
            if a1 > pi * 0.5:
                a1 = pi - a1
            print("{:.2f} degrees".format(degrees(a1)))
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

but my vertices are like this:

[image]

I can't imagine these angles are all less than 10 degrees especially since many appear to be on a 45 degree angle.

How can I correctly find the angles for a list of vertices in degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vert co as a vector is from origin point.**

[image]

Diagram where the red ico is the origin of a mesh and the other icos are the vertices.

Question code is calculating the angle designated as alpha above between the vectors defined by the  two vertex coordinates.

It appears you are after (beta) the angle between the vector made from two verts

```
vec = verts[i].co - verts[i - 1].co
```

and the x axis `Vector((1, 0, 0)).angle(vec)` or if the points do not all lie on same XZ plane, the projection of `vec` onto the XY plane containing point    `verts[i - 1].co`.

Example from python console, consider `vec = Vector((1, 1, 1))`  *ie* this is the result when subtracting `i-1`th vert from `i`th. Meaning if you travel `(1, 1, 1)` from `vert[i-1]` you will be at the location of `vert[i]`

```
>>> vec = Vector((1, 1, 1))
>>> x_axis = Vector((1, 0, 0))
```

Angle between 3d vectors

```
>>> degrees(x_axis.angle(vec))
54.735612876297274
```

To project as 2d vectors onto Y=constant plane, can get the signed angle between the 2d vectors ignoring y.

```
>>> degrees(x_axis.xz.angle_signed(vec.xz))
-45.00000125223908
```

Comment: the vertices are all on y=0

Comment: Okay. I get that co gets the angle from 0,0 but how do I get the angle between two of the vertices?

Comment: There is no angle between two points. without some other reference vector. Have explained what you are calculating in question (alpha) and how to get what I assume you are after the angle beta.  Can't go north west from point A to point B without having some reference of what north and west is.  Just looked at link posted in question, also points out that a reference vector is required.

Comment: or to put this another way, have used grease pencil to demonstrate the angles alpha and beta. Edit your question with diagram of expected  "angle between two vertices".

Comment: yes beta. The angle between the two points.

Comment: if co.angle() returns the angle of vertex2 relative to 0,0, I assume I have to subtract vertex1 from vertex2 then run co.angle on the result to get the angle between?

Comment: Please read answers (above and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34926/python-calculate-angle-between-vertices) mine explains  how to get the beta angle shown using the X axis as arbitrary reference vector.. The latter uses the Z axis as the arbitray "north" vector.  Points do not have an angle between them.